# How to update the initial state on Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm building a flutter page that shows to the users a list of the credit cards that are stored on the back-end and lets the user delete already existing cards.

To fetch the cards from the back-end I'm using [`initState()`](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#4-fetch-the-data). Note that `controller.getCreditCards()` returns a `Future<List<CreditCardSummary>>`:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _futureCreditCards = controller.getCreditCards();
  }
```

This List is then rendered using a `FutureBuilder`, just like [the documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#5-display-the-data) recommends:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<CreditCardSummary>>(
        future: _futureCreditCards,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Scaffold(
              // My page that renders all the cards goes here
              // Inside this future builder I can access the cards list with snapshot.data
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('ERROR');
          }
          // Show a loading screen while the data is beeing fetched:
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        });
  }
```

This is all working fine, the problem only begins when I need to update this data. For example, when the user deletes a creditCard, I want to delete the card from the List and to re-render the page with the new version of the List, but I don't know a good way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get updated data/ refresh the FutureBuilder, you need to reassign the future variable.

For your case, when ever you like to update,

```dart
_futureCreditCards = controller.getCreditCards();
setState((){});
```

Comment: Why isn't the line where you redefine the variable inside the setState's callback function?

Also, if I don't want to make a new HTTP request, which is done inside controller.getCreditCards(), can I just create a Future value with Future.value() and assign it to the variable _futureCreditCards?

Comment: You can put it, sometime I use `await` on upper line,  it is just my personal preference. if data is just can roam around withing this snippet and don't want to get update state from network, you can create another state bool ,this will be handy for it.

Comment: You can check [Fixing a common FutureBuilder and StreamBuilder problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg)